# Cannot send emails with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, email

I want to send emails using SftpClient from a Windows Service application.

I'm using the **.NET framework 3.5**

I've written the code below:

```
public void SendEmail(string sender, string host, string password, string port,
        string body, string subject, string[] receivers, List<Attachment> attachments)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = host,
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(port),
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, password)
        };

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        // sender
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sender);
        message.From = from;

        // receivers
        foreach (string receiver in receivers) {
            message.To.Add(receiver);
        }

        // attachments
        foreach (Attachment att in attachments)
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(att);
        }

        message.Body = body;
        message.Subject = subject;

        client.Send(message);
    }
```

The credentials that i've put are correct, but if i use port 587 i got:

"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions an_ip_address:587"

If i use port 465 (that should be deprecated) i got:

"System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

This happens also with windows firewall turned off.

All the parameters for sending emails (password, host, port...) are configurable by end users of this windows service.

Comment: No obvious issues with the code, so I'd check your SMTP host.

Comment: There were changes in the default setting in Net for smtp between 3.5 and 4.0 with credentials.  I'm pretty sure you code will work with Net 4.0, not sure about Net 3.5. If you are using Outlook you must use Network Credential.  If you are using  POP email account follow the email server instructions.  Are you on a corporate Network?  A corporate Network with Outlook enabled will use a proxy server and will not allow ports 465 and port 587 connect to a pop email service.

Comment: Which mail account are you trying to send? Different mail servers have different rules on port `587`, hence its worth trying some other server if they accept on `587` port.

Comment: Another point : You should disable anti-virus on your PC or provide permission on port 587.

Comment: I'm trying with gmail, so i'm using "smtp.gmail.com". I'm also trying from my home, hence using Internet. I'm going to check antivirus settings.